# Runtime rewriting with ocpsoft rewrite - Java

Tags: java, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, ocpsoft-rewrite

I'm developing a web application that provides some pages.
I require to rewrite the URL of these pages and I would like to use this framework http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite.

All works fine, but the problem is that I need invoke the configuration in a particular moment of startup so I can send a list of link to be rewrited.

I know that is possible but I haven't some experience with this framework.. (If you know other frameworks that allow to do it please tell me).

Thakns for all Bye.